# How to find the povinces where the longest Road of Ecuador begins and ends? (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

For a project, I have to find the longest road (codigo) in Ecuador and display the provinces (provincia) where it starts and ends using SQL. The data is provided in a table (see Figure). Each row represents a road segment and has a geometry (geom column). Of course, a road is built up by a number of segments having the same name (codigo).

[image: 1]

I already have the following code, which returns the longest road and the length in kilometres:

```sql
select v.codigo as road_name, 
sum(ST_Length(geom)/1000) as length_km, v.provincia as province  
from vias v
group by v.codigo
order by length_km desc
limit 1
```

I am still struggling on how to get the provinces (provincia) where this longest road starts and ends. Does anyone know how to write the code?

Comment: Does that code really work as the other non-aggregated column, `v.provincia`, is not in `GROUP BY`. Maybe it is functionally dependent on `v.codigo`? But wouldn't there be many roads in a province?

Comment: Yes! I checked and I uploaded the code where i was trying to reach the result, but it doesn't work. Beneath, you can find the code that does work and results the name of the longest road and the length in km.                                                                                                  select codigo as road_name,sum(ST_Length(geom)/1000) as length_km from vias v
group by v.codigo
order by length_km desc limit 1

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can extract the rows that correspond to the longest road. There's no information in the schema displayed in the image that's a good indication of where the start and the start province (At least, I don't understand the data set well enough). This is a set based approach using CTE (Common Table Expression).

```
with TotalLengthOfRoads
as (select  codigo as road_name, 
            sum(ST_Length(geom)/1000) as total_length_km  
    from vias 
    group by codigo)
select v.*
from vias as v
inner join TotalLengthOfRoads as tlor
    on v.codigo = tlor.codigo
    and tlor.total_length_km = (select max(length_km) 
                                from TotalLengthOfRoads);
```

Comment: Thanks! You are right that it you can't know which is the starting and which is the ending province. I just need the 2 provinces, the order is not important.

Comment: Is it possible to share the whole schema and a column/field that indicates whether a city is the start/beginning or end of the road? I there's a field like that then a restriction clause (where) at the end of the above statement would get the desired result.